# I want to pass my custom object in soap body element , how to do it?

Tags: java, web-services, soap, jaxb, saaj

I'm trying to call a webservice using JAXB SAAJ. I use wsdl2java to create web service objetcs. Now i would like to pass one of this object in soap call. How can I do this? I want to pass my custom object in soap body element , how to do it?

My code:

```
SOAPBody soapbody = soapmessage.getSOAPBody();
SOAPBodyElement element = soapbody.addBodyElement(soapbodyName);
element.addChildElement(myCustomObject); <-- it gives error here that I can not pass my object here.
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to marshal it to the SOAPBody using a `JAXBElement` and the `ObjectFactory` generated by wsdl2java:

```
JAXBElement<MyCustomObject> myCustomObjectElement = 
    new ObjectFactory().createMyCustomObject(myCustomObject);
jaxbContext.createMarshaller().marshal(myCustomObjectElement, soapbody);
```